# PLACEHOLDER - Stack Exchange Electron app

Tags: app, placeholder

**Stack Exchange Client.**

I created this post for getting write access to testing my application for desktop application.
**Language**: JavaScript

**Technology** Electron v1.8.2 beta-2

**Source code**: https://github.com/X-tymchenko/StackExchangeClient

**License**: MIT